# Magento - Populate a dropdown from 'X' Store categories

Tags: php, database, magento

I am in the process of customising our search filters on our Multi-Domain Magento install and was wondering how I can populate a dropdown with the category titles from a store depending on what store/domain you are on.

Probably a simple query but have so much going on at the moment I can't think where to start!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have specified your store (probably using a switch based upon the domain) you should be able to get a collection of the categories associated with that store id.